# elasticsearch - ngram, custom sorting, irrelevant results

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to implement searching through elasticsearch.
I'm using "edge_ngram" in the search field.

When searching I get irrelevant results (e.g. i search for "abcd" and i got "abc..." results), so I want to use the "min_score" filter, the problem is that this filter doesn't work if I use custom "sort" (then I get "score": null) for the results.

I have to make the min score filter work even with the custom "sort", or make my "analyzer" doesn't give me irrelevant results (for "abcd" i would like resulstrs "abcd*" not nothing more).

mappings:

```
'search_by' => [
    'type' => 'text',
     'analyzer' => 'autocomplete'
]
```

analizer:

```
"analysis" => [
    "analyzer" => [
        "autocomplete" => [
            "tokenizer" => "autocomplete",

        ],
    ],
    "tokenizer" => [
        "autocomplete" => [
            "type" => "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram" => 3,
            "max_gram" => 10,
            "token_chars" => [
                "letter"
            ]
        ]
    ] 
    ...
]
```

query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "search_by": {
                                    "query": "abcd"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "must_not": [],
        "should": []
    }
},
"min_score": 2,
"from": 0,
"size": 24,
"sort": [
    {
        "order_by": "desc"
    }
]
```

Comment: The problem is not the scoring but the way you're indexing and making queries. Please feel free to share your index mapping and query and we'll show you how to achieve what you expect

Comment: ok, i've added mappings and query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same analyzer for indexing and search time. It's a common mistake. So what you should do is simply this:

```
'search_by' => [
    'type' => 'text',
     'analyzer' => 'autocomplete',
     'search_analyzer' => 'standard'        <--- add this
]
```

Comment: if I use "standard" for "search analyzer" then my queries works only with exact match - there is not match after 3 letters.

Comment: Using the standard analyzer at search time helps you. You can use the `prefix` query and then you will be able to match anything from the same amount of characters (`abcd`) to longer strings starting with the same characters (`abcdefgh`)